# What is the purpose of the Ask Ubuntu General Room?

Tags: discussion

> General discussion around Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntu & official Ubuntu...

Please look at the "entries" there over the last few hours. Here's one:

> I would, but last time I did I got photoshopped into a horrible picture of a pornstar taking it from behind.

So, I ask what is the purpose of this room. In my opinion, it's very far from the stated purpose. I've even seen moderators of Ask Ubuntu carrying on sustained surreal conversations.

Just to be clear, I have no objection to the material I quoted or to mods carrying on surreal conversations, but please could the stated objective of the room be modified to reflect its actual usage?

Comment: So, you are asking for the description to be changed?

Comment: It's a bloody chat room, what do you expect? If there's nothing Ubuntu-related to talk about, is everyone supposed to remain silent until that changes?

Comment: [btw, the description has been almost the same since '11](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22room%20topic%20changed%20to%20Ask%20Ubuntu%20General%20Room%3A%22&Room=201&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

Comment: @Braiam *And* for a long time it also included a "usually it's just off-topic nonsense" section.

Comment: @FEichinger so because it's a bloody chat room, something has to go on all the time? Bloody brilliant.

Comment: @Braiam, is asking for the stated objective to reflect what's going on unreasonable?

Comment: FEichinger's point is that it's a chat room, so stop complaining when people use it as such. And yes, I do think it's brilliant. Nice compliment.

Comment: @Seth, what exactly do you mean by "stop complaining"? Do you mean that posting such a question in Meta is wrong? Or do you think it's just not worth complaining about: things will stay as they are?

Comment: @vasa1 no, posting on meta was the right thing to do, I think I must take responsibility to the reaction you had (even though I didn't actually post on your question) because my initial reaction in chat after you posted this was "oh, another person is complaining about stuff I do" and I feel that may have influenced the outcome here a little. Meta is the correct place to post queries about anything to do the with the site and the way it works.

Answer (score 9):

It's a chat room.
It's there for our users to relax and chat in. Not every message will —*or should*— be about Ubuntu.

I'm less concerned about the subjects talked about and more concerned by the *way* people talk to each other. The room is governed by the same rules as the main site:

- The Stack Exchange terms of service (et al)
- The Ubuntu Code of Conduct (yup, that's in the [Ask Ubuntu terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)):

  > When accessing the [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), [meta.askubuntu.com](http://meta.askubuntu.com), or [chat.askubuntu.com](http://chat.askubuntu.com) sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the most current Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at [ubuntu.com/community/conduct](http://ubuntu.com/community/conduct), and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu.

If we see people being wilfully horrible or causing bedlam (so that others can't *use* chat), we'll politely ask them to slow down or step out. This does happen from time to time.

Comment: I don't see anything about a code of conduct in the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.canonical.com/terms-and-conditions) (couldn't find anything Canonical calls "Terms of Service"). The [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct) seems to be its own entity.

Comment: @Cerran It's in [*our* Terms and Conditions](http://stackexchange.com/legal) (end of section 4. Restrictions): "When accessing the askubuntu.com, meta.askubuntu.com, or chat.askubuntu.com sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the most current Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu."

Comment: Oh, right; thanks for the clarification, though it should have been obvious.

Comment: +1 for the ubuntu code of conduct.

Comment: Oli, Ubuntu Code of Conduct is no longer mentioned in the Stack Terms of Service. Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324001. Also, please consider editing your answer accordingly.

Comment: @RandomPerson I'd rather fix the T&Cs

Comment: @Oli So, you're gonna talk to SE staff about it?